# Vector binning algorithm in Perl

Tags: perl, vector, hash

I have the following vector:

```
19.01
20.2572347267
16.4893617021
19.0981432361
36.3636363636
20.41
```

It's actually much longer, but that doesn't matter. I need an algorithm to bin these values into a hash. The hash keys must be floating point values that start from the minimum value + 1 (in this case 17.48...) and increase by 1. The values of the hash must be the number of elements that fall into the corresponding bin, i.e. the end result should be:

```
$hash{17.49}=1
$hash{18.49}=0
$hash{19.49}=2
$hash{20.49}=2
$hash{21.49}=0
$hash{22.49}=0
.
.
.
$hash{35.49}=0
$hash{37.49}=1
```

Please help guys.

Comment: and what is your question exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Came up with a sweet solution, hopefully somebody else will also find it helpful.

```
use POSIX;

sub frac { $_[0]-floor($_[0]) } #saw this little function posted somewhere, quddos to the guy who came up with it

for (my $x = ${min_value} + 1; $x <= ${max_value} + 1; $x += 1) # if you don't need the zeroes, remove this loop
{
  $bins{$x} = 0;
}

foreach my $n (@array)
{
$bins{floor($n+1)+frac($min_value)}++;
}
```

floor() or ceil() (and use POSIX;) should be used instead of int(), because int() can produce erenous results - 278 may be internally stored as 277.99999999997899999 (for example), so int(278) turns out equal to 277, which may mess up your computation. Read this somewhere, but can't find the link...

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use Data::Dumper;

use List::Util qw{ min };

my @vector = qw( 19.01
                 20.2572347267
                 16.4893617021
                 19.0981432361
                 36.3636363636
                 20.41
              );

my %hash;

my $min = min(@vector);

for my $n (@vector) {
    my $diff = $n - $min;
    ++$hash{ 1 + $min + int $diff };
}

print Dumper \%hash;
```

If you need the zeroes as well, just add the follwoing before the loop:

```
my $max = max(@vector);

my $i = $min;
while ($i <= $max) {
    $hash{$i++} = 0;
}
```

(And include `max` in the `use` clause, too.)

Comment: Many thanks choroba. Can someone come up with something a little more simplistic, because I need to understand how the code works. My solution seems to work on the test vector, but I'm not entirely sure about it.